# How to create Rotation Matrices in octave on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, octave, rotational-matrices

I'm trying to create a rotation matrix in octave, similar to rotx() in MATLAB.
I've found this [link](https://octave.org/doc/v6.1.0/Vector-Rotation-Matrices.html) which provides some information about it and states that it is part of octaves geometry functions. So I installed the geometry package version 4.0.0 but it seems like rotx() isn't a part of it.
Does anyone know if it may be another package they are referring to?
Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I should add that I'm using Ubuntu and the newest version is octave 4.4.2-1ubuntu1. The link I mentioned is from the newest octave version for Windows. Maybe octave on Ubuntu just doesn't provide the ability to create rotation matrices?

Comment: is your package loaded? (`pkg load geometry`)

Comment: Yes it is. I also tried other funczions from the geometry class and they work.

Answer (score 0):

The rot*() functions were added in newer versions of Octave your link was for version 6.1
It looks like 4.4.2 came out in 2018 https://wiki.octave.org/Release_History

For this, the geometry package is not needed.

I understand your confusion.
Because the file is located in the directory scripts/geometry/ for the main Octave program.

I see two solutions

1. Try to update to 6.1, you may have to build it from source.
   https://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_Debian_systems
2. It's FOSS so you can find the code here https://hg.savannah.gnu.org/hgweb/octave/file/b4906d3eeb63/scripts/geometry/rotx.m
   and make your own local .m file.